# Download many files from NPM

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm currently working on a hobby project where I try to analyze many NodeJS packages and the best source for such packages is obviously npm.
Is there any possibility to download many (500+) packages from npm. Maybe the 500 most popular or also randomly selected packages - I don't really care.

Just to clarify. I am not looking for some "half-legal" way to download these packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `npm install` does not download just a single package, but also all its dependencies. Therefore a relatively large project will download many packages and I guess with about 5 big projects there will be more than 500 packages in total, in no time.

As a real life example, here is a script from one of my projects that will install more then 1000 packages:

```
npm install vue

npm install vue-router
npm install connect-history-api-fallback

npm install vuex

npm install @vue/cli
npm install @vue/cli-service-global

npm install axios

npm install material-design-icons-iconfont
npm install vue-template-compiler

npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

Comment: Yes this is a very good point - I combined it with this tool https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-package-downloader and got exactly what I needed. Many packages as .tgz files. Thank you :)